# listview sort ascending in Android

Tags: android, database, sorting, listview, firebase

I work in this project but I don't know how can I display the listview in reverse (ascending order )

Artistlist class

```
public class Artistlist extends ArrayAdapter<Artist> {

private Activity context;
private List<Artist> artistList;

public Artistlist(Activity context,List<Artist> artistList){
    super(context,R.layout.list_layout , artistList);

    this.context = context;
    this.artistList = artistList;


}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();

    View listViewItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_layout,null,true);

    TextView textViewname = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    TextView textViewGener = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    Artist artist = artistList.get(position);

    textViewname.setText(artist.getArtistName());
    textViewGener.setText(artist.getArtistGener());

    return listViewItem;
}
```

}

how can I display the listview in reverse (ascending order )
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this line of code before sending the list to the adapter

```
Collections.reverse(artistList);
```